# IBM Worklight 6 - Windows 8 Tablet append function exception

Tags: jquery, windows, exception, ibm-mobilefirst, tablet

We recently started to test our App that is already working for Android, IOS and WP8 on Windows 8 Tablet (i.e W8 desktop app)

As we tried to run it, the App started and closed right away. Going a step further with debugging we found out that an exception being thrown from the WLJQ.js (see the image), more precisely append: function() at line 5964

With the exception details in mind and after some investigation that directed us to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767331.aspx, we came to a solution hacking the WLJQ.js file, which using a MS API to skip the injection validation.

[image]

So far so good, however I am quite confident changing an internal worklight file is not the appropriate solution, thus the code we have done might break other platforms.

Basically we changed this at WLJQ.js file:

```
append: function() {
  return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
      if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
      this.appendChild( elem );
      }
   });
```

by this

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
      var self = this;
            MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
                self.appendChild(elem);
            });
```

Software version: Worklight 6.0.0
Visual Studio 2012

Any clue on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Worklight's jQuery for your app?  Rather than changing WLJQ.js, I would remove the line:

```
<script>Window.$ = Window.jQuery = WLJQ</script>
```

And replace it with an explicit load of jQuery from your app.  jQuery 2.0 is supposed to be Windows 8 ready, so I'd start with that.

You don't say whether you use jQuery mobile.  That would cause problems even if you are using jQuery 2.0.  But at least if you are using a copy of jQuery from your app, modifying that isn't going to cause the issues that modifying WLJQ.js would.

Comment: Hi Dave. We are using JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and the embedded Worklight JQuery. So in order to have it fixed should I import and use another JQuery set of files ? I was not keen to do it. 
Also hacking WLJQ.js is not of much help as it gets replaced on each build

Comment: all you need to import is the single jquery js file into your project and into your main html.  it is a common practice, and insulates your code from changes/updates to wljq.  I agree, editing wljqjs is NOT the way to go.